# How to run this Decision Tree with MLlib?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I come from using Scikit-learn to run ML algorithms, so MLlib is rather new. With that being said, I did play around with Cloudera's github from a recent presentation and I am left with a question.

Say I am doing binary classification using a decision tree. I want to predict whether an object is an apple, or an orange. The two parameters that go into the features portion is of a list [x(float), y(binary)]. X will indicate the weight of the object, and y will indicate either 0 or 1 (smooth or bumpy).

I then have a list that is also binary, (0 = apple, 1 = orange). When I was using Scikit-learn, I would save them into something like this:

```
features_list = [[140, 0], [150, 0], [160, 1], [170, 1]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

In this, each label 0 or 1 will correspond to the item in the features_list. So the first 0 is the label for the feature [140, 0] etc.

Now when I go about training my model, my code looks like this:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(ml_list, labels)
```

When I would make a prediction, the code I would write would look like this:

```
print(clf.predict([180, 1])
```

When looking at the MLlib documentation, it seems that the parameters are 'labelscol' and 'featurescol'. I tried passing my ml_list and labels into those parameters and it threw an error.

My question would be, is there any way that I can run an ML algorithm like I did with Scikit-learn by using these two lists with MLlib? Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you seen this:- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html#examples

Comment: @VivekKumar I have seen that, but I am confused as to whether I can pass lists instead of column names as feature/labels.

Comment: Why not find out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ML (i.e. the DataFrame-based API) instead of MLlib, since the latter is headed for [deprecation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#announcement-dataframe-based-api-is-primary-api).

```
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier

features_list = [[140, 0], [150, 0], [160, 1], [170, 1]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]

dd = [(labels[i], Vectors.dense(features_list[i])) for i in range(len(labels))]
dd
# [(0, DenseVector([140.0, 0.0])), 
#  (0, DenseVector([150.0, 0.0])), 
#  (1, DenseVector([160.0, 1.0])), 
#  (1, DenseVector([170.0, 1.0]))]

df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(dd),schema=["label", "features"])

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(maxDepth=2, labelCol="label")
model = dt.fit(df)

# predict on the training set
model.transform(df).show()  # 'transform' instead of 'predict' in Spark ML
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
# |label|   features|rawPrediction|probability|prediction|      
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
# |    0|[140.0,0.0]|    [2.0,0.0]|   [1.0,0.0]|      0.0|
# |    0|[150.0,0.0]|    [2.0,0.0]|   [1.0,0.0]|      0.0| 
# |    1|[160.0,1.0]|    [0.0,2.0]|   [0.0,1.0]|      1.0| 
# |    1|[170.0,1.0]|    [0.0,2.0]|   [0.0,1.0]|      1.0|     
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+

# predict on a test set:
test = spark.createDataFrame([(Vectors.dense(180, 1),)], ["features"])
model.transform(test).show() 
# +-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
# |   features|rawPrediction|probability|prediction|
# +-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+ 
# |[180.0,1.0]|    [0.0,2.0]|  [0.0,1.0]|       1.0| 
# +-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

**EDIT**: Here is how to initialize Spark:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error that says "NameError: name 'spark' is not defined". I am rather new to Spark, how would I define this?

Comment: @rmahesh see edit for a minimal initialization example. Let me know if you get further errors, as I work these things in the Databricks cloud, where Spark is already initialized and I may be forgetting something...

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I believe that edit almost solved my issue completely. But I am stuck with this error at the 'df = spark.createDataFrame' statement: AttributeError: 'Builder' object has no attribute 'createDataFrame'  Is there something that I should have initialized beforehand?

Comment: @rmahesh ooopss... my bad! there should be a `.getOrCreate()` at the end (added)

Comment: I think I had some issues installing Spark on my machine, but when I ran this on Spark using Databricks, it ran perfectly. I do have a couple questions, why are we creating the variable 'dd'? And also, why 'maxDepth=2'? Couldn't 'maxDepth=2' be replaced with 'featuresCol= "features"'?

Comment: Additionally, with using transform instead of predict (which I am used to doing in Scikit-learn), how would I go about predicting something the label of feature '[180, 1]'. I tried simply replacing the variable 'df' in the transform statement with this list and it threw an error.

Comment: @rmahesh 1) `dd` is just an intermediate var - you could put the list comprehension inside `sc.parallelize`, but it would not look nice 2) check the docs for the `DecisionTreeClassifier` args https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier - in fact, even my `labelsCol="labels"` is not needed, since it is the default value 3) you should transform your test set the same way as `df` for predictions - e.g. `test = spark.createDataFrame([(Vectors.dense([180,1]), ["features"])`

Comment: @rmahesh All in all, you have to experiment a little to get a feeling - the documentation provides enough code snippets you can play with & adapt - kindly accept the answer if it is OK